# How to fetch details with while loop and display with foreach[MySQL and PHP]

Tags: php, binding, mysqli

How to fetch details with while loop and display with foreach?
Need to do this with bind....

```
$stmt= $db ->prepare("SELECT quote_autor, quote_text FROM quotes")or die($db->error);
if( $stmt !== FALSE ) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($quote_autor,$qupte_text);
$records= array();
while($stmt ->fetch()){
$records[]=$stmt ->fetch();
///??????
}
foreach($records as $rec){
//???????
}
```

Comment: whats the problem here? your question is unclear, if this is just about fetching, just use the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: Problem is how to put details into array and then diplay them...

Answer (score 0):

Using `while` to fetch the records:

```
while($records[] = $stmt ->fetch());
```

Using `for-each` to loop through after fetching

```
foreach($records[] as $record) {
    echo $record['COLUMN_NAME'];
    // use var_dump or print_r to know more
}
```

#### Edit:

If you want to print all the names, instead of using `for-each` you can do:

```
echo implode(", ", $array);
```

Comment: Geting this: Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal ) Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal [1] => Bil Gates ) Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal [1] => Bil Gates [2] => Albert Einstein ) Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal [1] => Bil Gates [2] => Albert Einstein [3] => Albert Einstein )

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt= $db ->prepare("SELECT quote_autor, quote_text FROM quotes")or die($db->error);
if( $stmt !== FALSE ) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($quote_autor,$qupte_text);
$records= array();
while($dyna=$stmt->fetch()){
    array_push($records,$dyna);
}
echo "<table>";
foreach($records as $rec){
    echo "<tr><td><b>Autor: ".$row[0]."</b></td><td><p>".$row[1]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This is array otput:Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal ) Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal [1] => Bil Gates ) Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal [1] => Bil Gates [2] => Albert Einstein ) Array ( [0] => Blejz Paskal [1] => Bil Gates [2] => Albert Einstein [3] => Albert Einstein )